# can't access api's by private ipaddress

Tags: angular, nginx

I have created a web application using Angular 8, in the backend I have used 3.6, I have deployed the UI in one server and Backend in another server, for deploying the code I am using azure ubuntu 18.04 VMs.

When I am calling the APIs from the UI server with DNS name the response is coming, but when I changed DNS name to PRIVATE IP ADDRESS it is showing this error:

[image]

**In Backend Server**

In the backend server, I have created a service like this:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Gunicorn instance to serve appapis internally
    After=network.target

   [Service]
   User=approot
   Group=www-data

   WorkingDirectory=/home/approot/appapis
   Environment="PATH=/home/approot/appapis/venv/bin"
   ExecStart=/home/approot/appapis/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 10.0.2.22:4532 wsgi:app



   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What is your goal here? What is your benefit of calling an IP that can change over a DNS name that does not change?

Comment: when we use the DNS name, the request will go outside of the internet and it will come again, the response will take time, Instead of that If we call in locally, we can reduce the response time. @gerstams

Comment: That menas besides your instance in Azure you have one running locally? What is your setup here? Can you please elaborate on this and add context + code to your question

Comment: I am running my VM's in the same Instance @gerstams

Comment: So you are running both applications within the same Ubuntu instance? If so, did you try calling the backend via localhost?

Comment: I tried..It worked with the backend when I am trying with the angular, then i am facing the problem @gerstams

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot quite see what you are doing. What worked in the backend? And What technology are you using there, e.g. Spring Boot Java or .NET C#?